# reading and plotting txt file in autocad

Tags: autocad

I want to read a txt file in autocad and plot them (line/polyline).
it may looks like

```
1 x11 y11 z11.......x14, y14,z14  % polyline 1
..
n xn1 yn1 zn1.......xn4, yn4,zn4  % polyline n
```

I want to know what is best and easy way to do this. What programming language I should use.
What are useful links or is there somework already done in this direction.
Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No programming language required! Just create a text file and type AutoCAD commands in the file the same way you would at the AutoCAD command prompt. Save the file with the .scr extension and you can either drag the file onto the AutoCAD window, or use the script command in AutoCAD to find and run the command script.

More info: http://www.upfrontezine.com/tailor/tailor19.htm

I actually use Python to generate these command scripts. With the power of a modern language, and throwing in some AutoLisp, you can do surprisingly sophisticated things. I've used this to model a complex steel tower for a cablestay bridge, and for testing model geometry for Larsa modeling.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways you can do it.

**Simple solution**

***Script file***

Creating a script file is easier and quicker
http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20Map%203D%202010%20User%20Documentation/HTML%20Help/files/WS1a9193826455f5ff47b7aa4b11fbe75ecf1-65dc.htm

***AutoLISP automation***

This is also easier and quicker plenty of online resources available.
http://www.pixelgraphicsinc.com/AutoLisp_Tutorial01.html

Best but complicated solution

**.NET C# plugin**

This is the best option as it lets you do more than basic things.
If you like to do coding. This is fun. you can create a plugin using .NET C# and read the txt file to create the line segments.

Let me know how you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectARX in C# as well as C++.
C# will be a better choice.

Just read your text file using StreamReader using C# System.IO library.

Create a array of points specified in text file.

Finally create the Polyline using given points and Using Transient in ObjectARX you can display the Polyline.